# XML security objective-c

Tags: xml, security

I have an app which connects to xml generated by server. I would like to know how can i secure  the connection between the app and the server to avoid the one will spoof the url of xml source and use it outside of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of XML is arbitrary,  you are just transmitting data structures between the client and the server and the same security concerns are present.  In the context of XML based protocols you have to worry about [xml injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_XML_Injection_%28OWASP-DV-008%29).

In general you can **never trust the client**,  the remote API you provide will always be accessible to the attacker.  If you try to enforce such rules on the client you'll violate [CWE-602: Client-Side Enforcement of Server-Side Security](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/602.html).

Answer (score 1):

Watch WWDC 2011 Session 208 (Securing iOS Applications).  There is a great section in there on creating secure network connections.

You can get that (and more videos) [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/).